# Android emulator device does not open devices with google play sign in it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play, emulation

Android emulator device does not open devices with google play sign in it, it opens devices without google play sign. But the problem stays in black screen when I open devices with google play sign
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsrwu.png)